# AWS ec2 exposed port is not working for Kubernetes forwarded port

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, kubernetes

I am new to devops. I have created an ec2 machine and opened the port 8080, while I am running a simple server I am able to access it publically.

> http://localhost:8080 (from within the ec2 container) => hello world
>
> http://ec2-15-206-178-112.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080 =>  hello world

Now I have installed a Kubernetes server which is accessible using kubectl from this instance, I am running a simple server on one of the pods and forwarded the port to ec2 8080 port.

> kubectl port-forward pod/frontend-7496d5f6b8-clfx4 8080:80

Now from my Ec2 instance I can access it

> http://localhost:8080 (from within the ec2 container) => hello world from pod

But I can not access it publically ( port 8080 is open in my security group )

> http://ec2-15-206-178-112.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080 =>  Connection refused

Can someone point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes port forwarding by default binds only to `127.0.0.1`. That is why you cannot access it using the public interface.

Use the following command to bind to all interfaces:

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0
```

You can check the related GH Issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40053).